# Odoo13 - Does caching /web/content makes sense?

Tags: nginx, caching, odoo, odoo-13

Typical Odoo installation guide suggests to configure Nginx to cache paths like this:

```
/web/static
```

And they are skipping paths that look like this:

```
/web/image
/website/static
/web_sale/static
```

I would guess that they should also be cached. But what I'm wondering on is this:

```
/web/content
```

This is the path to `js` and `css` from `assets_common`, `assets_frontend` etc.

Does caching them can lead to some problems? I don't really see why it would be the case.

This is my Nginx config:

```
location ~* /[0-9a-zA-Z_]*/(static|image|content)/ {
    proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
    proxy_buffering    on;
    expires 864000;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
}
```